# Windows 8 looking for Office 2013 - I have office 2010

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office-2010

I have a computer with Windows 8; when I try to open a file the computer looks for Office 2013.  How do I change the settings so it uses Office 2010 instead?
I know about opening Word or Excel first and then opening a file.  I am a teacher and have a pre-algebra book on my hard drive which runs with a program - I cannot go directly to Word to open the files.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look: http://www.gcflearnfree.org/windows8/16

To Change the Default App:
You may prefer to change the default app for certain types of files, so that they'll always open in the new app when you double-click them. For example, you may want your photos to always open in Windows Photo Viewer instead of the Photos app.

- In Desktop view, right-click the desired file.
- From the drop-down menu, click Open with and select Choose default program....
- Select the desired app. If you don't see the app you want, click More options.

Answer (score 0):

Open this:

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Default Programs
```

and set the Office 2010 Programs as default handlers

```
Set as Default
```